# How to attach an image, name and file size to a table td as href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to attach an image, its name and file size to display in `<a>` tag inside a table `<td>` as href. But during on click I am getting an error  `Uncaught TypeError: td.appendChild is not a function at Image.img.onload`. Any help on this would be much appreciated ?

```js
    function upload(){
      var img = new Image();
      var td = $('.someclass>tbody>tr>td>a');
      img.onload = function() {
        td.appendChild(img+fileName);
      };
      img.src = 'file:///C:/somename/Tests/avatar.JPG'; 
      var fileName = img.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
    }
```

```html
    <table class="someclass"> 
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="filename">
          <a target="_blank" href="http://somelink.com"></a>
        </td> 
        <td class="filesize">
        </td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="rtggBJHGHGH123JHGH">
    <span>Upload</span>
    <input onclick= "upload();" type="file" name="file">  
    </div>
```

Comment: `td` in this case is a jQuery object.  jQuery does not expose the `appendChild` method.  Just use the `append()` method that it does have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're assigning a jQuery object to your variable, you can directly use the `append()` method:

```js
...
var td = $('.someclass>tbody>tr>td>a');
img.onload = function() {
    td.append(img);
};
...
```

Also, since you defined `img` as an Image object, you must call the `src` attribute in your `replace()` statement, as well as append the objects independently:

```js
...
img.src = 'file:///C:/somename/Tests/avatar.JPG'; 
var fileName = img.src.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
img.onload = function() {
    td.append(img).append(fileName);
};
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQueries `.append()` method to add the image and filename data to the selected `<td />` table cell. Also, to extract the name and size data for a file/image selected from a file input element, consider using the `FileReader` API:

```js
function upload(event){

  // Extract file from event
  var file = event.currentTarget.files[0];
  if(!file)
  {
    return;
  }

  // Use a file reader to access data from file field
  var reader = new FileReader();
  
  reader.onload=function(event)
  {

    var img = new Image(); 
    img.onload=function()
    {
   var td = $('.someclass>tbody>tr>td>a');
      
     // If image loaded from file, append it to your td
     td.append(img);
            
 // Extract name from file object and append it to your td
        td.append($('<p>').text('Name:' + file.name))
  
     // Extract size from file object and append it to your td
        td.append($('<p>').text('Size:' + file.size))
    }
    img.src=event.target.result;
    
  }
  
  // Pass file to file reader
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="someclass"> 
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="filename">
      <a target="_blank" href="http://somelink.com"></a>
    </td> 
    <td class="filesize">
    </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<div class="rtggBJHGHGH123JHGH">
<span>Upload</span>
<!-- Correct input to pass event data to upload() -->
<input onchange="upload(event);" type="file" name="file">  
</div>
```

Comment: One question, where should I give the image path  `file:///C:/somename/Tests/avatar.JPG'`

Comment: Hi @soccerway, using the answer above, the image path is provided by the user when the file is selected through the file selector input - you will usually find that browsers make it difficult to access files directly off your file system by file paths like this: `file:///C:/somename/Tests/avatar.JPG` 

hope that helps!